# Unable to delete zip files from DB server location using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, xp-cmdshell

I have a Zip file created and I am unable to delete it using the below command.

`xp_cmdshell 'rm "F:\EXIS\Reports\Individual.zip"'`

It gives an error saying File not found, when I can actually see the file.

I tried using `xp_cmdshell 'del "F:\EXIS\Reports\Individual.zip"'`

But, this asks for a confirmation, which I actually cannot input.

Please suggest if anything,

Thanks.

Comment: "when I can actually see the file" - *Where* can you see it? The server doesn't necessarily have the same drive mappings as you do; it may not know anything about `F:\` at all.

Comment: @KenWhite : I can see the file in server location only. I an able to delete other files of others types which are in the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is more generic in the sense the file is not found with the current credentials of SQL Server process while accessing the indicated location.

I suspect it is a problem of rights, so please assure the SQL Server proecess has rights to delete file in that location. An alternative suggestion is to perform a "dir" on that location.

Comment: Thanks for the "dir" idea. Zip file name was different. So was not deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `del`in silent mode like:

```
xp_cmdshell 'del /Q "F:\EXIS\Reports\Individual.zip"'
```

And also: if SQL Server is running on a different machine the path must of course be valid for that machine.

Comment: Hi, I get the below message on using the answer u suggested.

`Could Not Find F:\EXIS\Reports\Individual.zip`

Answer (score 1):

--change server configuration like :
--Script to enable the XP_CMDSHELL
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 GO

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.

RECONFIGURE GO

-- To enable the feature.

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 GO

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.

RECONFIGURE GO;

```
  DECLARE  @BackUpPath varchar(255) ,@sqlQuery varchar(255)

  Set @BackUpPath='D:\All DB BackUp\TestDB.bak'

  IF dbo.fn_FileExists(@BackUpPath)=1 
  BEGIN

     SET @sqlQuery='DEL /Q "' + @BackUpPath + '"';

     PRINT @sqlQuery

     EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sqlQuery

     IF dbo.fn_FileExists(@BackUpPath)=0

     BEGIN    

     PRINT 'File Deleted'

     END

     ELSE

     BEGIN    

     PRINT 'File not Deleted'

     END 

   END
```

IF @BackUpPath  contains space , you must type your path like "your
   path"